# Quick way to get the value from array with another array giving condiition

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

Lets say there is an `array $filter_from_array_id = array(2,8,52,45,7)`

And then there is another array

```
$main_array = array([0] => array(id=> 8,name => 'data-ryhryh'),[1] => array(id=> 7,name => 'data-ththt'),[2] => array(id=> 66,name => 'data-kukuk'),[3] => array(id=> 85,name => 'data-gegegeg')
```

I want a result something like these `array([0] => array(id=> 8,name => 'data-ryhryh'),`

You see the point, id is filtered.

I will get the result through looping but if the main array is larger then it can consume time , I wonder if there is a short way than looping through all.

I would also want to know if php has something inbuilt for this one or anything close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an associative array from `$main_array` so you don't have to loop to find the IDs.

```
$main_assoc = array_combine(array_column($main_array, 'id'), $main_array);
$result = [];
foreach ($filter_from_array_id as $id) {
    if (isset($main_assoc[$id])) {
        $result[] = $main_assoc[$id];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a function for that: [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check a value in an array.

```php
array_filter(array $array [, callable $callback [, int $flag = 0 ]]) : array
```

*Iterates over each value in the array passing them to the callback function.
If the callback function returns TRUE, the current value from array is 
returned into the result array. Array keys are preserved.*

You don't need any loop to doing such operation. [PHP array functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).

**Edit**: Code rewritten due to the variable visibility.

Corrected and tested *PHP7 for brackets array() == [ ]* here: [phptester](http://phptester.net/)

```php
// Declaring $filters ... is not visible in function
// and can't be pass as arguments to the callback.
function filters () {
 return [2,3,52,45,7];
};

// The array to filter
$main_array = [['id' => 8,'name' => 'data-ryhryh'], ['id'=> 7,'name' => 'data-ththt']];

// Filter data having an id in the array of filters.
// Adding & to improve memory usage
$result = array_filter($main_array, function (array &$item) {
  return in_array($item['id'], filters());
});

print_r($result);
// result = Array([1] => Array([id] => 7 [name] => data-ththt))
```

Note: the `keys` of the `$main_array` will be preserved

Comment: Sorry, code rewritten and tested unless the $filters is global variable, you should use a function to provide the array to the callback.